# bcrypt invalid elf header when running nodeJs - linux

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, node-modules, bcrypt

Facing issue in node js getting error of invalid ELF header. but the error accoured only in ubuntu ( 22.04v). thanks in advance .

in my localsystem im getting error of "invalid ELF Header" in node js when running node program (in linux )